# Deploy a Spring Boot JAR in a GemFire server

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have implemented GemFire server-side event handler (`CacheLoader`) using Spring Boot as I will have to call multiple external services to load data.

When i tried to deploy the JAR (Spring Boot FAT JAR) in GemFire, I am getting the error message below:

```
gfsh>deploy --jar=C:\GIT\client-cache\build\libs\client-cache.jar
Response was null for: "deploy --jar=C:\GIT\client-cache\build\libs\client- 
cache.jar". (gfsh.isConnected=true)

Could not read command response.  Error occurred while executing "deploy -- 
jar=C:\GIT\client-cache\build\libs\client-cache.jar" on manager. Please check 
manager logs for error.
```

Can anyone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, *Gfsh's* `deploy` command cannot handle FAT JAR deployments uploaded to the GemFire cluster.  Even if it could, there would be nothing to bootstrap the Spring `ApplicationContext` to construct, configure and initialize your GemFire `CacheLoader` (I suspect a Spring bean so that you can inject with multiple managed (other beans in the Spring context) data sources (services)??), and then register the `CacheLoader` with the Region.

There are really only a few options here:

1. Use Spring [Boot] to configure and bootstrap Pivotal GemFire. I have written a whole section on this in the ***Spring Boot for Pivotal GemFire (& Apache Geode)*** *Reference Guide Appendix*, [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#geode-cluster-configuration-bootstrapping).
2. Use Gfsh's `--spring-xml-location` option to the `start server` command to configure and bootstrap Pivotal GemFire with Spring (by default XML, but you could use a small snippet of XML to enable annotation config and use Spring `@Configuration` classes in your FAT JAR from there on).
3. A third way to handle this is to use the SDG's `SpringContextBootstrappingInitializer`.  More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-bootstrap).

Either way, you need to ensure that the Spring container is bootstrapped somehow either directly or indirectly by GemFire.

This should get you started with a few ideas.